# How to use timestamp as chart's x-axis?

Tags: python, datetime, charts, bokeh

I am trying to make a chart with Bokeh and I have a `datetime` list as below.

I would like to set the `datetime` as my x-axis but seems like Bokeh can't show this chart correctly.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Thank you.

```
datetime = ['2017-11-23 20:56:16',
            '2017-11-23 20:56:47',
            '2017-11-23 21:00:56',
            '2017-11-23 21:01:26']

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=350, title="the trend")

p.xaxis.axis_label = "time"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "price"
p.line(datetime, price, line_width=2)

output_file("test.html")
show(p)
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use keywords as variables. You are using `datetime` as variable which should be avoided. The datatype of time should be always be in accepted datetime format.

Check the changes that I made to the code which shows the `timestamp` as x-axis.

**Note:** Since the data is very small it will show only hours of same day and if data is very large it will show date,time and year.

Graph:

```
datetimes = ['2017-11-23 20:56:16',
            '2017-11-23 20:56:47',
            '2017-11-23 21:00:56',
            '2017-11-23 21:01:26']

datetimes = np.array(datetimes, dtype=np.datetime64)

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=350, title="the trend")
p.xaxis.axis_label = "time"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "price"
p.line(datetimes, [45,67,70,60], line_width=2)
show(p)
```

The output look like this: [image: Graph]

I added some sample data and made another graph which shows date.

```
date_range = pd.date_range('2017-11-23 00:00:00', periods=72, freq='H')
price = np.random.randint(20,100,72)
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=350, title="the trend")
p.xaxis.axis_label = "time"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "price"
p.line(date_range, price, line_width=2)
show(p)
```

The graph will look like:

[image: Graph2]

For reference [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#datetime-axes)

Comment: Got it !  Thanks a alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your `datetime` list contains strings, these should be `datetime` objects (or Pandas' equivalent).

(Btw, to avoid confusion, it might be better to avoid using module names for a variable, like `datetime` in this case.)

You could parse them with the `datetime` module, but Pandas can also be convenient, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

datetime = pd.to_datetime(['2017-11-23 20:56:16',
                           '2017-11-23 20:56:47',
                           '2017-11-23 21:00:56',
                           '2017-11-23 21:01:26'])
```

You can adjust the formatting of the axis labels with `DatetimeTickFormatter`.

edit:
If you dont want to use Pandas for parsing the dates, it can be done with the `datetime` module like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['2017-11-23 20:56:16',
         '2017-11-23 20:56:47',
         '2017-11-23 21:00:56',
         '2017-11-23 21:01:26']

dates = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), dates))
```